# MIP GAP couldn't be set properly

Tags: c++, cplex

I am solving a MIP in IBM ILOG Cplex. I have set the relative MIP GAP and absolute MIP gap to 0 ,but the gap was reported in engine log was upper than 0. also when I run the model by default values (1.0E-4,1.0E-6), the gap is reported in engine log is upper than 1.0E-4 (sometimes even 6%). and the surprising thing is that even the time of calculation was small(below 1sec). I think maybe other settings is needed besides mip gap to set it to zero to obtain optimal value of objective function. one another thing is that my other settings are as default. I appreciate if anyone can help me.

this is the result of one of my run(relative MIP GAP is set to 0 but the reported gap is 1.13% as you can see):

```
        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer     Best Node    ItCnt     Gap

      0     0    15619.2777    30                  15619.2777      204         
      0     0    21532.4345    31                    Cuts: 92      300         
      0     0    22240.7958    65                    Cuts: 50      389         
      0     0    22374.7172    46                    Cuts: 63      452         
      0     0    22428.5062    28                    Cuts: 31      475         
      0     0    22447.7754    48                    Cuts: 28      517         
      0     0    22486.3137    39                    Cuts: 34      542         
      0     0    22486.3137    40                    Cuts: 13      557         
      0     0    22486.3137    30                 ZeroHalf: 4      558         
      0     0    22486.3137    28                    Cuts: 15      583         
*     0+    0                        23225.6696    22486.3137      583    3.18%
      0     2    22486.3137    28    23225.6696    22486.3137      583    3.18%
Elapsed real time =   0.36 sec. (tree size =  0.01 MB, solutions = 1)
*    26    20      integral     0    22743.1173    22486.3137     1126    1.13%

GUB cover cuts applied:  2
Clique cuts applied:  23
Cover cuts applied:  9
Implied bound cuts applied:  105
Flow cuts applied:  1
Mixed integer rounding cuts applied:  30
Zero-half cuts applied:  74
Gomory fractional cuts applied:  3

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    0.31
Parallel b&c, 4 threads:
  Real time             =    0.25
  Sync time (average)   =    0.02
  Wait time (average)   =    0.06
                          -------
Total (root+branch&cut) =    0.56 sec.
```

beforehand thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried a small non-zero value for the MIP gap tolerance? The default is 1e-6. It may be the case that setting the MIP gap tolerance to zero does something "special". So I would see what happens with the MIP gap set to different values like 1e-2, 1e-4, 1e-6, 1e-8

Comment: yes. I tried the default value but the gap was much more than 1e-4 (about 5%)!

Comment: Are there some more lines of output in the log after this? I think that I have seen cases where the last line in the B&B part of the log shows a larger gap than is reported at the end of the run.

Comment: thank you for your cooperation dear Tim. I check it again. but in my software there isn't any more line after ''Total (root+branch&cut) =    0.56 sec.''! How can I fix it then? and when I solve my problem with a meta-heuristic algorithm ,the value of objective function is lower than optimal objective function reported by Cplex and the gap is more than set gap (1e-4) . also I've checked my feasibility of solution found by meta-heuristic algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim said in the comment, it is the last line of the log file that actually shows the final solution (upper and lower bounds) and not the last line of the tree log part.

Here is an example:

### [image]

It seems that the problem is as follows:

- CPLEX reports an optimal solution, with a default gap of 10e-4, but it reports 1.13%
- You have found a better solution, in which you have checked that it is feasible

For the first bullet, CPLEX does not actually report that the gap is 1.13%. The gap *was* 1.13% when it was reported during the search.

The fact that it returns a solution, that should obey the default tolerances, is a proof that, using your formulation the optimal cannot be less than what is reported.

Since you are sure that there is a better feasible solution, you have a few options.

- Try to inject your known solution to CPLEX before it starts the optimization. One way to do this is using [goals](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSSA5P_12.6.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/progr_adv/goals/20_heur_soln.html). This might be somewhat complicated so you might want to ..
- Print out the model and evaluate manually that the solution you claim is better is feasible with respect to the constraints you have entered (recommended method).
- Add a constraint that the objective function value should be less than or equal to your solution's objective value augmented by a small quantity (something around 10e-3 should be OK). If your solution is feasible for formulation, you should get it, otherwise there is a bug and the solution is infeasible. I do not like this method because if there are multiple optimal solution you can get funny results, but usually it works).

All in all, try to debug the model and let us know. It is a fairly complicated model and it is easy to have missed something (i.e., adding a constraint that you did not mean to add).

If all this fail and you still find yourself wondering what is going on, you might want to submit your model to [IBM's official forum](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSSA5P_12.6.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/progr_adv/goals/20_heur_soln.html). If there is indeed a bug in the solver they will take care of it and let you know.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you loannis. in my software the last line (Solution Status) isn't shown. Do you know any way to fix the setting to show this line? and there is still one more reason to claim that the gap isn't set properly.   when I solve my problem with a meta-heuristic algorithm ,the value of objective function is lower than optimal objective function reported by Cplex and the gap is more than set gap (1e-4) . also I've checked my feasibility of solution found by meta-heuristic algorithm.

Comment: If the last line is not shown then it is an implementation issue (maybe a bug). Could you post (or link to) your code and the input file? Also, if the last line is not shown then you cannot know what is the optimal solution reported by CPLEX, and therefore it cannot be compared with your meta-heuristic algorithm. If your model object is called `mdl`, you can try adding `std::cout << mdl.getObjValue() << std::endl;` after your call to `mdl.solve()`? This will give you the objective value reported by CPLEX. If there is no output from this line, there is a problem. Do you use callbacks?

Comment: I coded the model in Cplex not C++ and I don't know C++. I checked my objective function by "the solution with objective value'' shown in the problem browser window. this is my model in cplex:

Comment: dear loannis, sorry I am beginner in this field and don't understand you well. I coded the model in Cplex not C++ and I don't know C++. I checked my objective function by "the solution with objective value'' shown in the problem browser window. this is my model in cplex:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xj6lop40kgr7d3a/ILRP.rar?dl=0 

thanks for your help.

Comment: Dear loannis, I appreciate your help. I changed some parts of my algorithm code because of some reasons and I never encountered this problem again. maybe the reason was because of that.